# 500 Internal Server Error (invalid characters) on LastModified http header

Tags: php, apache, caching, internal-server-error, last-modified

I have a php download script that sends a `Last-Modified` http header like this:

```php
header("Last Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

that worked fine for a very long time.
But now I tried to use that script in another project and this header line causes an Error 500 in xampp.

The logfile shows the message:

```
AH02429: Response header name 'Last Modified' contains invalid characters, aborting request
```

All examples that I can find in google (e.g. [http-response-header-last-modified](https://ansas-meyer.de/programmierung/php/http-response-header-last-modified-und-etag-mit-php-fuer-caching-setzen/)) and
even documentations like [Mozilla-Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) or [rfc7232#2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.2) suggest the same format.
So I am realy wondering why apache/xampp have a problem with that header.

Comment: Maybe some Timezone or Locale settings?

Comment: No, i printed the line in the header as page-output and it matches exactly the expected header line. `Last Modified: Mon, 24 Aug 2020 08:18:23 GMT`

Comment: `Last Modified` and `Last-Modified` are two different things. The former has never been valid.

Comment: OMG... @Cbroe you are right, that was a embarrassing typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like noticed by [cbroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) there was an typo in my header-name.
The point is, that maybe old servers did not complain about missspelled headers, and newer servers trigger an `internal server error`.

The Correct line should be

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

`Last-Modified` instead of `Last Modified`.